Local cartesian coordinates on Riemannian manifold
I'm wondering is possible for every given metric $g=g_{ij}dx^i \otimes dx^j$ on $M$ and for every given $p\in M$ to find such chart $(U, \varphi)$ around $p\in U \subset M$ that the metric $g|_U$ in induced coordinates $u^i:=\pi^i \circ \varphi$ has the form
$$g|_U=du^1\otimes du^1+\ldots + d u^p\otimes du^p-du^{p+1}\otimes du^{p+1}-\ldots - du^{p+q}\otimes du^{p+q}$$
on entire $U$? Or is too much and we can find such form of $g$ only in $p$?
I'm wondering over it, because in general relativity we belive we can describe spacetime locally, for instance around the Earth, in cartesian coordinates such that the metric has the form
$$g=-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 $$
don't we? I'm wondering if we can prove it mathematically using differential geometry.

It is quite easy to check that if there are coordinates like this, then the metric is flat (i.e., the curvature is zero). The answer to your question follows immediately from that. I suggest that if you haven't studied Riemannian geometry yet, you should do so. If you have, then I suggest reviewing relevant parts of it as you study general relativity. Of course, there is circumstantial evidence that the answer is no, since if such coordinates existed, we would always use them.

You're discussing the metric on the ambient spacetime, not the induced metric on a submanifold.

@Deane I'm not asking whether $g$ can be globally expressed in this form, because I know it's impossible. I'm asking whether $g|_U$ can be expressed this way.

My comment applies to the local situation. Compute the curvature.

@Deane so we cannot find such chart/coordinate system even locally? :O Even for a very "small" $U$?

Curvature is a local invariant. You should verify that if a metric on an open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as $$ g = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 +dz^2, $$ then its Riemann curvature tensor is identically zero. Therefore, if a metric $g$ on an open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ has nonzero Riemannian curvature, then there do not exist coordinates on $U$ such that $$ g = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 +dz^2. $$

No, this is impossible in general. The condition you have stated is equivalent to the Riemann curvature vanishing identically. So for example on the sphere $S^n$, this is not possible (in fact for every point and every neighbourhood $U$ (no matter how small) there is no coordinate chart with this property, because the round unit sphere has constant sectional curvature $+1$, which is not zero).
In general this is only possible at one point. I believe part of your confusion comes from the sloppy use of terminology in Physics, where they misleadingly use the term “locally”, going against a hundred years of topological terminology. When a physicist says “the metric is locally flat” they mean confusingly that “for every point $p\in M$ there is a chart $(U,\phi)$ such that $g_p=\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i(dx^i)_p^2$” where $\epsilon_i\in\{-1,1\}$ (so in GR this would be of Lorentzian signature). So, to summarize:

Physicist’s “locally” = Mathematician’s “infinitesimally” (i.e one tangent space at a time)

Another fun thing we can do is the construction of normal coordinates, meaning for each point $p\in M$ there exists a coordinate chart $(U,\phi)$ such that in these coordinates, we have $g_{ij}(p)=\pm \delta_{ij}$ (with the correct signature) and $\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}(p)=0$ for all $i,j,k\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ (or equivalently, $g_{ij}(p)=\pm\delta_{ij}$ and $\Gamma^{i}_{\,jk}(p)=0$ for all $i,j,k\in\{1,\dots, n\}$).
